# Convert HTML to PDF using Cypress.IO

Tags: cypress

I'm wondering is it possible to convert the page visited using `cy.visit(url)` to pdf ?
Chrome api has `Page.printToPDF`
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF
Is it possible to access chrome api through Cypress.IO and print current page to pdf file ?
I searched internet but did NOT find proper solution

Comment: you can found below the anser for you question and the **github** reference repository for more examples and don't hesitate if you have any other questions...  **Lapwood**

Answer (score 5):

I have been playing around with the `Cypress.automation()`, this is how I managed to to the pdf out to the project root folder.

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com')
  .then(() => {
    return Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
      command: 'Page.printToPDF',
      params: {
        transferMode: 'ReturnAsBase64',
      },
    })
  })
  .then(data => cy.writeFile('./document.pdf', data, 'base64'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Python (using the pdfkit library):

```
import pdfkit
# Replace 'input.html' with the path to your HTML file
pdfkit.from_file('input.html', 'output.pdf')
```

Alternatively, you can use online converters like [SwifDoo pdf](https://www.swifdoo.com/) free online converter, or similar services. These websites allow you to upload your HTML file or specify a URL, and they will convert it to a PDF that you can then download.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes you can but using Cypress.automation** to send **Page.printToPDF** command and that return a **promise** :

```js
    it("prints the page to PDF", { browser: "!firefox" }, () => {
      cy.visit("/");
      cy.get(".new-todo")
        .type("write Cypress tests{enter}")
        .type("use Cypress.automation{enter}")
        .type("???{enter}")
        .type("Profit!{enter}");
    
      cy.get(".todo-list li")
        .should("have.length", 4)
        .then(() => {
          // print the application to PDF
          // https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF
          return Cypress.automation("remote:debugger:protocol", {
            command: "Page.printToPDF",
            params: {
              transferMode: "ReturnAsBase64",
            },
          });
        })
        // Log the PDF or do what you want with the pdf or save it using cy.writeFile
        .then((pdf) => console.log(pdf)); 
    });
```

**REFER TO :**

https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-grep-example/blob/add-print-spec/cypress/integration/print-spec.js

**THE FULL CODE :**

```js
    const url = 'https://www.google.com';
    const filename = './www-google-com.pdf';
    cy.visit(url)
      .then(() => {
        return Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
          command: 'Page.printToPDF',
          params: {
            transferMode: 'ReturnAsBase64',
          },
        })
      })
      .then(data => cy.writeFile(filename, data, 'base64'))
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen? Where is the pdf?

Comment: @R.Winkles the pdf is response of promise add then  .then(() => { return Cypress.automation(.....); }).then((pdf) => {  cy.writeFile('name.pdf', pdf); })

Comment: Yes, that looks better - but you would need to specify the encoding.

Comment: @R.Winkles i take into account that you are familiar with this library and promise

Comment: I got `Error: 'Page.printToPDF' wasn't found`